# Find the column in the right of the column with the largest and second largest number

Tags: r

```
A Ai B Bi C Ci  
1 4  2 6  3 5 
2 5  3 5  2 6 
3 6  1 4  1 4
```

So first I need to find the max value and second largest value among column(A,B,C) and put it column name(tie.method=first).

then I have to find the column in the right column(A,B,C), which is column(Ai,Bi,Ci). And put in Ai, Bi, Ci base on the value of max(A,B,C).

Should look like this:

```
A Ai B Bi C Ci  max   maxi     2ndmax 2ndmaxi
1 4  2 6  3 5    C    5(Ci)      B     6(Bi)
2 5  3 5  2 6    B    5(Bi)      A     5(Ai)
3 6  1 4  1 4    A    6(Ai)      B     4(Bi)
```

Is it possible to do that?

Wondering what should I put in the last line

```
y <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3),Ai=c(4,5,6),
                B=c(2,3,1),Bi=c(6,4,5),
                C=c(3,1,2),Ci=c(4,6,5)) 

af=cbind(y[,c(1,3,5)])
y$maxcol=colnames(af)[apply(y[,c(1,3,5)],1,which.max)]
y$max_val=
```

Comment: In the first row, `Bi` is 6  `Ci` value of 5.  Not clear about the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = grep('i',names(data),invert = T)
j = t(apply(data[i], 1,order,decreasing =T)[1:2,])

data.frame(data,
  matrix(names(data[i])[j],ncol = 2,dim = list(NULL,c('max','2ndmax'))),
  matrix(data[-i][cbind(c(row(j)),c(j))],ncol = 2,dim = list(NULL,c('maxi','2ndmaxi'))))
 A Ai B Bi C Ci max X2ndmax maxi X2ndmaxi
1 1  4 2  6 3  5   C       B    5        6
2 2  5 3  5 2  6   B       A    5        5
3 3  6 1  4 1  4   A       B    6        4
```

data:

```
structure(list(A = 1:3, Ai = 4:6, B = c(2L, 3L, 1L), Bi = 6:4, 
    C = 3:1, Ci = c(5L, 6L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: in R, when a number has L, it is just an integer. eg  write on your console `class(3L)` and also `class(3)` then you will see the difference

Comment: found this when I run the code above, did I miss anything?
Error in apply(a[i], 1, order, decreasing = T) : object 'a' not found

Comment: sorry, `a` is your data. replace `a` with data. Run it now

Comment: Thanks! What should I do if I don't need "second largest" data, I tried turn every 2 to 1 in the code but the outcome doesn't match

Comment: @Renaissance in your final data, just remove the rows you do not want.